# Cannot register DLL after installing into GAC in installshield2015

Tags: dll, gac, dllregistration, installshield-2015

I am new to Installshield2015 and i need to Install the DLL into GAC and Register from the same location.
I have tried several options by creating a custom action and also by creating a supporting file(batch file) and running it from cmd.
I am able to Install it in the GlobalAssemblyCache but i cannot register it.

Can anyone please help me some inputs on how to install and register the DLL after installing into the location.
I have read several formus but could not see much info on this.

Tried:

1. Creted a GlobalAssemblycache folder in IS2015 and tried install/register from the %windir%\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL
2. created a custom action and tried to execute "Installutil -i mydll.dll"
   3.created a suuporting batch file and added as new component and tried to execute batch file from command prompt. i added a custom action to run the batch file.

These are the major action i have taken but also verified by changing the Installsequesnce of the Installer.

also looked into this 
[How to register a dll into GAC with Installshield](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43736996/how-to-register-a-dll-into-gac-with-installshield)
but no luck

Thank you for the help...!!

-Ra Ra

Comment: When you say register, do you mean for COM interop, such as through regasm? I believe the linked question just wanted to install into the GAC (and only mentioned tools like regasm due to some confusion).

Comment: Its a .NET component which i am using. I can install the component by developer tool (cmd prpt). I am using INSTALLUTIL.exe to register the component from the cmd prompt. But when i try to use installshield i can put the DLL to the location but cannot register.

Comment: Is your custom action deferred in system context? It sounds like it's trying to modify machine resources.

Comment: Yes i am using the Action "In-Script Execution" and Set it to "Commit Execution to System Context".